# Can't discover bluetooth mouse and keyboard through CoreBluetooth (macos Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a problem with devices using CoreBluetooth framework. Basically I need to copy the functionality of standard bluetooth discover app in OSX, so I did th following:

```
let bluetoothManager = CBCentralManager()

//Lifecycle

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bluetoothManager.delegate = self
}

//delegate method

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOn:
        print("powered on")
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    case .unknown:
        print("state unknown")
    case .resetting:
        print("resetting")
    case .unsupported:
        print("unsupported")
    case .unauthorized:
        print("unauthorized")
    case .poweredOff:
        print("powered off")
    }
}
```

This code only discovers iphones and TVs, but ignoring the apple's keyboard and mouse. Is there something I'm missing? Maybe I need some services to define in withServices:?

For now I just print peripherals into console:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("discovered some perilherials", peripheral)    
}
```

I searched the [bluetooth.com](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services) specs, but with no luck

Any advice would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Bluetooth can only discover BLE GATT profile devices. For legacy devices and profiles (such as the HID profile advertised by a keyboard) you will need to use the [IOBluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth)